# how to load double space value to drop down angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to load json value to drop down using the code below

```
<select style="white-space: normal !important" class="form-control" [disabled]="!orgNameModel.orgName" (change)="bankAccountList();" required [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':bankdetailcreateform.submitted && bankname.invalid}" #bankname="ngModel"  [(ngModel)]="bankNameModel.bankName" name="bankName"> 
     <option value="">--Select--</option>
     <option *ngFor="let bank of bankNameModel"> {{ bank }} </option> 
</select>
```

my json file

```
["type one","type  three"]
```

Values are loading well, but the problem is "type  three". Double space is not rendered in the drop down. "type three" show with single space. How can I show this value with double space?

[image]

Also check the above image. I want to load that value with same spaces, but it is loaded with only one space.

Comment: `white-space: normal`: Sequences of white space are collapsed. Newline characters in the source are handled the same as other white space. Lines are broken as necessary to fill line boxes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: i updated my question. can u check

Comment: Can you tell the why do you want to display like that because even the white-space are ignored in drop-down , when you select that option then in the **.ts** file you will get the value with multiple white-space as it was before . i can provide a code if you say .

Let me know if you are concern with display only .

Comment: i found the solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi option tag of select does not allow the css attribute word space directly. So I found a workaround for this using the angular directive.
For that please create a directive like this : 

@Directive({
    selector: '[doubleSpaceTransform]'
})
export class DoubleSpaceTransformDirective implements OnChanges {

    @Input() bankName: string;
    inputElement: HTMLElement;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
        this.inputElement = el.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.bankName) {
            const splitBankName = this.bankName.split(' ');
            const child = document.createElement('span');
            for (const bank of splitBankName) {
                child.innerHTML = child.innerHTML + '&nbsp; &nbsp;' + bank;
            }
            this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, child);
        }
    }

}

Then use this directive in the option tag like this 

<option *ngFor="let bank of bankNameModel" [bankName]="bank" doubleSpaceTransform></option>

Please make sure to pass bankName input here.

I hope this helps
```